# Using Websockets with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble getting AWS EB to work with websockets. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436110/websockets-with-aws-and-elastic-beanstalk) question and have set the protocol to TCP. I've also been reading [this](https://mixmax.com/blog/deploying-meteor-to-elastic-beanstalk-1) article but I'm not sure if it's still relevant.

Any suggestions on what I could be missing? So far whenever I try to set up a websocket I just get a 404 response. Not sure if it's relevant but I'm also accessing the instance over https.

Let me know if any other information is necessary! Thanks!

Comment: did you check the security group?

Comment: I'm looking at it now... what should it be? I have a HTTP listener on port 80 and custom TCP listener on port 8443.

Comment: you should open ports 80 and 8443

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `config` file in your `.ebextensions/` that specifies the settings below, as described [here](https://mitchellsimoens.com/websockets-behind-elastic-beanstalk/).

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

[edited to add specifics from the link]

Comment: Please add the information behind the link, not just the link. Websites can disappear or get reorganized.